# Sending data from android app to a phpMyAdmin server using HTTP post method

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android application development and i want to send three parameters Latitude , Longitude and Bimari(which i am mentioning in my code below) to phpMyAdmin server via internet. The problem is that the two parameters are  being incorrectly sent to server side i.e Latitude=0.0 Longitude=0.0 and only Bimari is being displayed correctly.  Can anyone please tell me why are latitude and longitude being sent on server incorrectly?I have searched alot and have found about AsyncTask but couldn't understand how to implement that in my case .Thanks alot for reading !

MainActivity.java is as follows:-

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.sushma.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";


String nn, nn1, nn2, nn3, nn4, nn5, nnf;
String sss1, sss2;
String s;

double lat, lng;
LocationManager lm;
TextView lt, ln;
String provider;
Location l;
private View view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria c = new Criteria();



    provider = lm.getBestProvider(c, false);
    l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (l != null) {

        lng = l.getLongitude();
        lat = l.getLatitude();


    } else {

        System.out.println("No lat/long");

    }

    {


        LinearLayout l1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        l1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ambulance);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}


public void ongobuttonclick(View view) {
    this.view = view;

    Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.problems);

    s = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
    sss1 = String.valueOf(lng);
    sss2 = String.valueOf(lat);



    nn = "http://192.168.2.8/tech/new_predict.php?Latitude=";
    nn1 = sss2;
    nn2 = "&Longitude=";
    nn3 = sss1;
    nn4 = "&Bimari=";
    nn5 = s;

    nnf = nn + nn1 + nn2 + nn3 + nn4 + nn5;


    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httPost = new HttpPost(nnf);
    try
    {
        httpclient.execute(httPost);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Output on my server:-

Latitude    Longitude   Bimari
0.0         0.0         Lungs       ( bimari as per selected by spinner)

Android version on my phone is 2.3.6  .

If you want i can add my logcat as well .

Comment: Your code is really hard to read due to the naming of variables. Anyway, have you checked the contents of lng and lat before sending them to the server?

Comment: Yes sir , i checked them by printing them on the console but output were lng=0.0 and lat=0.0.

Comment: You mean they were zero before sending them?

Comment: Sir the variables nn, nn1, nn2 , nn3 , nn4 ,nn5 are used so as to sum up the URL as a string together in nnf .                                              i.e nnf=nn+nn1+nn2+nn3+nn4+nn5;

Comment: Yes sir they were zero before sending to server .

Comment: Well, the problem is not with the data transferral to the server then, but rather with the lastKnownLocation that you get from the Android system. You'll probably have to ask the system to update the location as described in the docs https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html.

Comment: Yes sir i have tested that server side is working correctly , now let me see the link you have suggested .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code that come to mind:

1. Check if lat and lng are actually set. The values will only be set if your device detects a gps signal, which is naturally problematic indoors. Otherwise, they will remain as initialized - with 0.0.
2. Make sure to use the appropriate HTTP methods. Your code suggests a httpget, you should put parameters in post like this:

   `List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", lat);
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));`

Hope this helps.

Comment: just saw you're only calling getLastKnownLocation in your onCreate(). If the Locationservice is not in use before starting your app, it won't have had enough time to determine the location.

Comment: Yes sir actually i am getting null as l(l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);) in my console , so definitly the problem is somewhere in the GPS code .                                               Regarding the server side part scripting it is working perfectly fine .

Comment: are you testing on a real device or emulator?

Comment: real device Samsung Young S5360 .